# What is the "break/continue $var syntax" (will be removed in PHP 5.4)?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm looking at the [alpha 1 news about PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-06-28-1) and find some things that are removed.

In that list they talk about `break/continue $var syntax`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I assume, that this one is meant

```
break $c;
continue $c;
```

`break` and `continue` accepts a number, that specify the number of nested loops, that should be breaked up, or continued. Have a look at the example [at the manual](http://php.net/control-structures.break).

However, it seems, that `break` and `continue` are not usable with variables anymore. In my personal experience, this will affect .. nobody ;)

Comment: `break $var` is a horrible idea. Didn't even know it existed. O_O

Comment: Thanks. Luckily I never had this evil idea too :).

Comment: I hope _nobody_ had that idea :D

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I have been using PHP over a decade and had no idea this construct existed, much less was actually used by anyone.

Comment: For anyone who's concerned, break and continue can still be used with a fixed number. I checked the SVN commits ;)

Comment: I've used this before, I've actually found it pretty useful.  If you think this is ugly, just remember that the likely alternative is to use a `goto` :-/

Comment: @Robin: Nope, it isn't, both are ugly ;) But first remember, that we are talking about `break $var;` and not `break;` or `break 2;` (which both will keep working). However, the cleaner solution is `while(){}`/`do{}while();`. If you can work with it, you don't need to touch `break $var`; or `goto` in any time.

Comment: @Robin or even, construct better loops to aboid having to break an variable number of loops, so no need for gotos nor break X. I have never use any of those two things, neither I needed them.